# Nesting REACT app son IIS, resulting in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: reactjs, iis

One of our projects requires that we host multiple REACT-based apps from a single domain, in a nested configuration

> [www.mainapp.com](http://www.mainapp.com)
> [www.mainapp.com/app1](http://www.mainapp.com/app1)
> [www.mainapp.com/app2](http://www.mainapp.com/app2)

IIS configuration works fine for the main site, but when a call is made to a child application, the result is a 500 Internal Server Error.  Event Viewer provides no assistance with this.

Removing the routing rule on the main site, the child applications functioned as expected.  APIs function fine off the main site as well (.NET applications).

> ```
> <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
> <match url="(.*)" />
> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
> <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api" negate="true" />
> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/admin" negate="true" />
> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/tools/tokenization" negate="true" />
> </conditions>
> <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
> </rule>
> ```

One thing to note, tools/tokenization is configured as an IIS application and mounted as a virtual folder.  It works, but /app1 and /app2 do not (500).  For testing I converted app1 to an application, but it made no difference.

Comment: Check what exactly is the request that triggers the 500 error and which module returns that, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing Then you might move further to see what's wrong.

Comment: `/app1 and /app2`, what are app1 and app2? Your project folder or what? Using failed request tracking is currently the best option.